# Apache server 500 ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE when downloading excel file

Tags: apache

Apache server gives a 500 ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE when i try to download an excel file and the connection gets closed. However sometimes the file downloads but the page still shows ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE. Any ideas?